# TypeScript ignoring possibly unassigned variable when used in new closure

Tags: typescript

In "strict" TypeScript mode, this is an error:

```
let a: number

a.toString() // error TS2454: Variable 'a' is used before being assigned.
```

Obviously, because a is unassigned.

But, if `a` is used in a new closure*, TypeScript won't error:

```
let a: number

process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
  a.toString() // no error
})
```

Shouldn't TypeScript say something like "we don't know that has been initialized yet" therefore necessitating `a!.toString()` if the user knows it has been?

I know I could type `a` as `number | undefined`, but it seems like that's implicit based on me declaring `a` without assigning it at all.

**closures that are deterministically ran synchronously, like a self-invoking function, will error properly*

Comment: That closure is not deterministically synchronous so typescript can not know wheter a is assigned before that block runs.

Comment: TS doesnt know it in the moment of calling the callback the variable will/or not be there. Trying to block that would be wrong limitation.

Comment: @Eldar doesn't seem to be related to "not deterministically synchronous" https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/DYUwLgBAhgXBB2BXAtgIxAJwNwCgcDNF4BjMASwHt4J8KKAKASggG8cJoIBeCARlwC+eWg0a4cUAHRgKAZTAYy8AOZMsQA

Comment: @Eldar That's the point of my question. TypeScript can't know whether it's assigned or not, so why isn't it yelling at me, saying something like "a is possibly unassigned"